# How to loop through a vector to get the number of occurrences of a value?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `v1` that has 10,000 elements (each element's value is from 0 to 10) in it, and I have to do a for loop from 0 to 10 that goes through the vector `v1`.

So for the value 0 I need to go through the 10,000 elements of vector `v1` and increase the result `v2` by 1 every time the current element is equal to 0. Then I have to repeat this for all other possible values (1 to 10).

For example, `v1` is a vector like `[2,3,1,4,0,6,5,3,1,...,5]` that has 10,000 elements and I have to know how many occurrences of 0's, 1's, ... 10's there are. The result has to be a vector that's like `v2 = [500/10000 , 1300/10000, 1000/10000, 700/10000, ..., 400/10000]`, so it sums up to `10000/10000 = 1`.

I got upto the following code, which is still so wrong, but I hope you get what I'm saying.

```
for c = 0:10
    a = 0
    for b = 1:length(v1)
        if c==b
            a=1+a
        end
    end
    v2(c) = b
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). The easiest way to do this in MATLAB is to use the built-in [`histcounts`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) function, and specify the number of bins `nbins` as 11 (0, 1, ..., 10):

```
[v2,~] = histcounts(v1,11);
```

So far, `v2` will contain the number of occurences of each number, i.e. `[500, 1300, ...]` in your example. You could of course just divide it by 10'000 (divide by `numel(v1)`, the number of elements in `v1` and not a fixed number!), or you can just use the `Normalization` property of the histogram function and set that to `'probability'`. That way the *relative* number of observations is calculated. All put together gives you

```
h = histcounts(v1,11,'Normalization','probability');
v2 = h.Values;
```

Comment: That would probably work, however, you may also want to specify edges in case it is important to know the exact number of occurences of every entry and not just the distribution `h=histogram(v1,[-0.5,0.5,..., 10.5])` would give you the number entries with values 0, 1, 2, ..., 10.

Comment: @patrik thanks, I included that in my answer (though via the number of bins, not via the edges - less typing) and changed from `histogram` to the more appropriate `histcounts`.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of `histcounts`. I would guess this to be the successor of `histc`, though I cannot say for sure. However, I would not say that `histogram` is inappropriate. It is very likely that spyair wants this to be plotted later and this would make `histogram` the exactly the right function. However, it is not certain, why I submitted another answer in first place.

Comment: I wasn't either until now ;) I was about to submit an answer like yours using `histc` but thought I'd rather post something with the new `histogram` function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to count how many values between 0 and 10 are each in your vector v1. This should do the trick:

```
% Create example vector
v1 = round(10*rand(1,10000));

v2 = zeros(1,11);
for ii = 0:10
    % Count number of elements in v1 wich have a value of 'ii' and store the result in v2
    v2(ii+1) = numel(find(v1==ii));
end
```

The `find(v1==ii)` gives you all entries of `v1` with the value `ii` and `numel` counts them. You have to go through `v2`with `v2(ii+1)` as Matlab indices start at `1`.

A faster version to calculate this would be to use `sum(v1==ii)` instead of `numel(find(v1==ii))` as [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578555/how-to-loop-through-a-vector-to-get-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-value/32578908#comment53013548_32578908) wrote in the comment.

To check, that you counted all values correctly you can run `sum(v2)` whith should give you `10000` in this example.

Comment: As `find()` does quite some work which you don't actually need, you could also use `sum(v1==ii)` to count the number of elements which have the value `ii`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [histc](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) as well. That function is not creating a histogram, but it can be used to count the number of entries.

```
entries = histc(a,0:10);
```

calculates the number of entries which is 0,1, ...,10.

then you can find the distribution as `dist = entries./length(a)`. In case you want a histogram though, this does the same as the answer by [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32578852/2903371), using the edges extension, except it does not plot a histogram. In case you want the histogram plot as well, I recommend the other answer. If not, this will make it easier by not forcing you to find a way to close a plot after extracting the data which seems messy. However, if you want to generate the distribution in a continous manner by using perecentiles, then hist will make it easier. However, your distribution seems to be discrete, thus `histc` should be able to do the trick.